# Pressing <tab> after typing 'export VARIABLE=~/' clobbers the 'VARIABLE='

Tags: bash, tab-completion

I'm experiencing the following behaviour in bash that I find very annoying:

1. Type `export VARIABLE=~/`
2. Now I'd like auto-completion for the next segment of the path, so I press `<tab>`.
3. Bash clobbers the `VARIABLE=`, leaving just `export ~/`.

**Why is this happening?**

My bash version is 4.3.33, OS is Debian testing, terminal is Konsole.

Comment: Do you have any customized bash completion support enabled? What version of the bash-completion package are you using?

Comment: My bash-completion package is `1:2.1-4.1`. How do I tell if I have customized completion support?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue in my environment.

Comment: Using the same version of bash and the bash-completion package on my debian unstable system I can't reproduce this either. If you run `exec 9>/tmp/trace.out; BASH_XTRACEFD=9; set -x; export VARIABLE=~/<tab>; set +x; unset -v BASH_XTRACEFD` what do you see in the `/tmp/trace.out` file?

Comment: @EtanReisner: I had no trouble reproducing it with bash completions from the git repository, as long as COMP_WORDBREAKS does not contain an =. Does it on your installation? If so, do you know where the setting was changed?

Comment: @rici Removing `=` from `COMP_WORDBREAKS` does indeed cause this to occur for me as well. I don't know why the OP wouldn't have that in there (unless they removed it). It appears to be in the bash/readline default value from what I can tell.

Comment: What does `declare -p COMP_WORDBREAKS` output for you? Are you modifying that value anywhere in your shell startup scripts?

Comment: @EtanReisner: Right you are. On my system, the ' =' is being removed by `/etc/bash_completion.d/npm` (from the `nodejs` package). Extremely rude, that is. I should have looked more carefully through the bash source; I only checked the obvious startup files. (The default value is in `bashline.c`, variable `bash_completer_word_break_characters`.)

Comment: @rici Interesting about the `npm` completion. I wonder why they did that. It wasn't the most obvious thing to find in the bash source either (though only took a little bit of trail following).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Verify that `$COMP_WORDBREAKS` includes an `=`. If not, try this:

```
COMP_WORDBREAKS+==
```

If the `export` completion works to your satisfaction after that, then you need to figure out what startup file is changing `COMP_WORDBREAKS`.

For example, if you've installed node.js, the `npm` completion script (in `/etc/bash_completions.d/npm` removes `=` and `@` from COMP_WORDBREAKS.

Many completion scripts, somewhat annoyingly, change global settings. (For example, the standard Debian/Ubuntu completion scripts enable the `extglob` shell option.)

Comment: You're right on all counts: my `COMP_WORDBREAKS` did not have `=` in it, it was `npm` that was removing it, and re-adding it fixed the problem. Much thanks! Do you know what the purpose of `npm` removing it is?

Comment: @highcommander4: I don't know why npm does that. Unless you're abig fan of npm  and its completions, I'd suggest just deleting the npm file in the completions directory. Or edit it and remove the lines which chane BASH_WORDBREAKS.